# Get part of get html code from file_get_content

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I need a part of code html by a file from file_get_contents(url)

I do

```
$variableee = file_get_contents("http://url.com/path/to/file");
echo $variableee;
```

Ok now in Variableee I've all the url's code.
In this code there is a part that I need. I need a table with class name "table".

Es.

```
<div>text</div>
<span> text </span>
<table class="table">
<tr><td>Text that I need</td></tr>
</table>
```

How I can get it?
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data within PHP itself use the built-in DOM parser,

```
<?php
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML($variableee);

  $arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("table"); // DOMNodeList Object
  foreach($arr as $item) { // DOMElement Object
   echo $item->nodeValue;
 }
?>
```

**EDIT: Parse using the class name with DOMXPath**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($variableee);
$classname = 'table';
$a = new DOMXPath($doc);
$spans = $a->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), '   '), ' $classname ')]");
foreach($spans as $item) { // DOMElement Object
 echo $item->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is possible do the same but from class?

Comment: Yup, see the edited answer